# Opennms: How to enable "Not Monitored" monitor

Tags: opennms

Trying to set up JDBCQueryMonitor monitor. When I'm setting up the monitor in the same manner as in documentation: http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#_jdbcquerymonitor, it's shown as "Not Monitored" in Interface.

According to https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/FAQ-Configuration#Q:_Why_are_some_services_listed_as_Not_Monitored.3F it should be defined by status attribute in config file. But it's already set to "on"...

Comment: I added the service config to a wrong package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Not Monitored" on the service means basically, you have assigned a service but Pollerd has

- not found a service configuration for the given service name
- the IP interface does not match a Polling package which has a service configuration for the given service name

You should check the following things:

Click in the Node Detail Page in the Web UI on the IP interface where your JDBC service is assigned. In the top you will find the matching "Polling Packages" which are applied on this IP interface.

Check in the `poller-configuration.xml` if you have a service configuration for your JDBC service in the defined "Polling Packages". The service name is important, check if you don't have typos here.

Additionally and a often seen problem. People define the service configuration but miss the class mapping at the bottom of the poller-configuration file. Please verify if you have the configuration entry with something like:

```
<service name="OpenNMS-DB-Event-Limit" ...
```

and also assigning the monitoring class with

```
<monitor service="OpenNMS-DB-Event-Limit" class-name="org.opennms.netmgt.poller.monitors.JDBCQueryMonitor" />
```

at the bottom of the `poller-configuration.xml` file.